# Increase font size of whole web page on button click event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to increase font size in whole page when user click on increase button. It will be increase on bases of current font size. Following is sample code :

```
<div class='parent' style='font-size:15px'>
    <div class='c1'>div 1</div>
    <div class='c2'>div 2</div>
    <div class='c3'>div 3</div>
    <div class='c4'>div 4</div>
    <table style="font-size:17px">
        <tr>
            <th>test 1</th>
            <th style='font-size:11px'><div>test 1.1</div><div style='font-size:22px'>test 1.2</div></th>
            <th>test 2</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery code but it will not work properly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.parent').find('*').each(function(){
        curSize=$(this).css('font-size');
        arrCurSize=curSize.toUpperCase().split("PX");
        if(arrCurSize.length==2){
            //alert(arrCurSize[0]);
            $(this).css('font-size',((parseInt(arrCurSize[0])+2)+"PX"));
            //alert($(this).css('font-size'));

        }
    });
})
```

Comment: @MilchePatern it's no duplicated because in your link it will set fixed font-size and in my requirement i want to increase font size with any fixed amount of each tags using their current font-size...

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592932/jquery-match-elements-with-style-font-size-in-px/20593041#answer-20593041 where user wared provided a neet jquery selection that will most probably suit your needs.

Comment: I edited my answer with a solution for you.

Comment: Assuming that you can't modify the HTML part, are you able to override *non* inline styles? Indeed, the most annoying part comes from fixed sizes which are *not* defined from the style attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my previous comment, here is what I've made so far (again, assuming that you can't modify the HTML part) : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/JWUt9/. This solution is a bit dirty since it adds a style attribute and binds an extra `font-size` data to every element matched by the selector (in this case : `p *`). Furthermore, we have to loop through the entire set each time the user clicks the resize button. However, it allows to override fixed sizes defined from *non* inline styles.

If we had control over non inline styles, we could replace all fixed sizes from there by hand with `em` units for example, and we could do the same with inline fixed sizes via javascript. In the end, we could zoom in and out by simply modifying the container's `font-size` property, and descendant elements should resize automatically. Here is an interesting example from which we could start (scroll down a little to the first codepen demo) : http://css-tricks.com/theres-more-to-the-css-rem-unit-than-font-sizing/.

Comment: I wonder why this got accepted for an answer while some others were more straingt to the point of finding 'only' elements with inlined style to change the font-size.

Comment: @MilchePatern I guess this is due to this sentence : "it allows to override fixed sizes defined from *non* inline styles". But you should ask the asker directly :)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in one shot.

Just define the inner elements' font-size referencing its container font-size.

E.g:

```
<div class="container">
   <p class="par1">text1: 15px at start</p>
   <p class="par2">text2: 17px at start</p>
</div>
--------------------------------------------
.container {font-size: 10px}
.par1 {font-size: 1.5em}
.par2 {font-size: 1.7em}
```

The markup below, gives 15px to first paragraph and 17px to second. Because if the standard size setted in the container is 10px, then the conversion rates are:

- 1em = 10px // container initialization
- 1.5em = 15px
- 1.7em = 17px
- ... and so on ...

Now, you can update all font-size definitions, updating the container font-size.

Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6BS7/2/) to play with this idea.

Comment: Viktor, what happens when you are not able to reform the html markups?

Comment: See OP question, it is a case of inlined styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change font size of the body of whole page in a  button click as below.
here i changed the font-size in percentage.

```
$("#sizeUp").click(function() {

        $("body").css("font-size","70%");

 });
```

If you want to change each element size with some amount in each button click, then follow below coding..

```
  $('body *').each(function() {
      xsize= parseInt($(this).css('font-size')) + 1;    
        $(this).css('font-size', xsize+2);
  });
```

Comment: it will not working because it will set fixed 70% font-size of body and all the child element which inherit body's font-size.

Comment: @Dipen you are asked to change the font size of whole page only. you dont specify the size..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(this).css("font-size","+=2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was quite unclear (changing whole page font size) while your coding seems to target the specific container classed .parent 'childrens'.

[credits to [wared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1636522/wared)  and [Zaheer Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821057/zaheer-ahmed) ]

Your coding was close, but the simpliest jQuery method was to `.test()` with the `.attr('style')`

```
if (/font-size:[^;]+px/.test($(this).attr('style'))) {
        $(this).css("font-size","+=2");
    }
```

Here is your solution [jsFidled here](http://jsfiddle.net/wqM3V/9/) :

```
$("#trigger").click(function() {
    /* the overall body tag for relative units */
    $("body").css("font-size","+=5%");
    /* targetting inlined font-size in pixels */     
    $('*').each(function (index, value) {
        if (/font-size:[^;]+px/.test($(this).attr('style'))) {
            $(this).css("font-size","+=2");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably simplest to consider formatting your page for this functionality.  E.g. use a fixed original body font-size, and have all elements use a font-size percentage.  Then, you can simply use jQuery to set the body font-size, and all elements will adjust accordingly.

Comment: How about implementing this in someone else's work where you are contrain to work over some 'silly patching designer' ? Or what about when you use a plugin that do not apply to your html-css framework ?

Comment: Then this approach wouldn't work.  That didn't seem to be the OP case, and it's worth considering in a lot of situations.